# Extracting data from sql create statement using regex

Tags: java, sql, regex, java.util.scanner

I've got to extract some data from simple sql create statement.
I decided to use regex for that purpose.
Everything is ok until I put NOT istead of NOT NULL/NULL, not specyfiing `"nullability"` works too (returning null in group as intended).
When putting only NOT it skips columnname.

I've got the following code(atm only prints included, not event handling extracted data)
(Using finds within horizon because statements can be formatted differently)

```
String input = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Types_of_classes("
    + "columnname INTEGER NOT PRIMARY KEY," 
    + "name TEXT," 
    + "name2 datatype);";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
    s.findWithinHorizon("\\s*CREATE\\s+TABLE(?:\\s+IF\\s+NOT\\s+EXISTS)?\\s+(\\w+)[(]",input.length());
    MatchResult result = s.match();
    if (1 < result.groupCount())
        return;
    System.out.println(result.group(1));//printing tablename
    s.findInLine("\\s*(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)(?:\\s+((?:NOT )?NULL)?)?(?:\\s+(PRIMARY KEY)?)?,");
    //there will be added somethind in that regexp to handle FK's too
    result = s.match();
    for (int i = 1; i <= result.groupCount(); i++)
        System.out.println(result.group(i));
    s.close();
```

**output:**

```
Types_of_classes
INTEGER
NOT
null
PRIMARY KEY
```

Any advices on whole the extracting etc will be appreciated too!

Comment: I have to ask, **why** are you doing this?  What is it you're attempting to do (big picture)?  If you want a list of types used in a database, you'd probably have better luck going after the information schema tables, where the db will have collected all this information for you.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thank You for your response, as I said any advices are appreciated.The purpose is mapping sql tables to classes in java.
Information schema doesn't provide null or not null data, idk how about keys?

Comment: I might depend on what your RDBMS is, but of course it does - check whatever table contains constraint information, to start.  If it didn't have this information, how are you getting the `CREATE TABLE` statements?  Next problem - tables and classes don't usually map perfectly, or at least not for certain well-designed systems.  Key relationships are usually backwards, at minimum - in OO the parent will have a collection of child objects, but in the db the children have a reference to the parent.  Audit the output... and there's probably already a library that will spit this out, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The `NULL` portion of your second regex is written in a way that makes it required, and the space after `NOT` is written in a way that makes the words `PRIMARY KEY` not match since you put `\s+` infront of it, requiring at least one space (which was matched by the space after `NOT`), here's a modified regex (combination of both your first and second regexes) which matches up to the PRIMARY KEY column part

```
\s*CREATE\s+TABLE(?:\s+IF\s+NOT\s+EXISTS)?\s+(\w+)[(]\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)(?:\s+((?:NOT)?(?:NULL)?)?)?(?:\s+(PRIMARY KEY)?)?,
```

This is a great interactive site for playing with regex matches, with explanations of what is going on:

https://regex101.com/